# Playwright - nested locator calls

Tags: typescript, playwright

I have a structure like this I am trying to test:

```
<div custom-id=a>
  <div custom-id=b>
    <h1>one</h1>
  </div>
  <div custom-id=b>
    <h1>two</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div custom-id=a>
  <div custom-id=b>
    <h1>three</h1>
  </div>
  <div custom-id=b>
    <h1>four</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to query it in two parts.  First, get back all the custom-id=a nodes, then for each of those, get back all the custom-id=b nodes.

Based on previous questions I have asked, I was under the impression something like this would work:

```
const aNodes = await this.page.locator("custom-id=a");

for (let aNode in aNodes) {
  const bNodes = await aNode.evaluate(node =>
    Array.from(node.querySelectorAll('custom-id="b"')));
}
```

But when I try this, the IDE linter is telling me that aNode is a string.  I guess I expected that aNodes would be an array of something I could again query.

My apologies if you have already answered questions from me along these lines.  I am struggling to grasp some basics here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `locator` is not iterable per se. But you can use the `count` function to get the elements count and then `nth` to get one element at a time:

```
const aNodes = await this.page.locator("custom-id=a");
const count = await aNodes.count();
for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  const bNodes = await aNodes.nth(i).evaluate(node =>
    Array.from(node.querySelectorAll('custom-id="b"')));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, @hardkoded.  I edited your answer a little to define count, but I am still seeing this error relative to i < count:
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'number' and '() => Promise<number>'.
Any ideas?  Also, would you like a fruit basket or something... you rock!

Comment: I guess my edit needs approval, but I added:
const count = await aNodes.count;

Comment: And for anyone wondering about my other question: count should be count()... doh!